# Could metastasis be driven by a healthy organ?

Tags: cell-biology

Could the cancer cell be called to itself by the organ to which it will metastasize? Maybe when the cancer cell enters the bloodstream, it is not according to the seed-soil hypothesis, but by releasing the messenger molecules into the bloodstream by the healthy organ, it allows the cancer cell to perform chemotaxis on itself?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Do you want to know if metastasis happens by release of messenger molecules by the cancer cell which are taken up by the cells of the organ where the metastasis happens instead of cancer cells invading the organ?

Comment: @chris, I don't understand you either

Comment: Ok, easier: What do you want to know? You can either edit the question or we help you with it, no problem.

Comment: @chris, Since healthy cells have less glucose, I thought maybe by changing some gene expressions and synthesizing biomolecules, they could form a signaling network with tumor tissue.

Comment: @chris, Yes, attracting cancer will ultimately be to his detriment, but on the other hand he will be deprived of glucose. I thought it was like he might be stuck in a dilemma and going down such a path.

Comment: What's your goal here?

Comment: @krause, what do you want to say??

Comment: Why do you put "@krause"? There is no user "@krause", so what's the purpose of that? You seem to be attributing intention to someone or something that you refer to as "he". It is very unclear what you are saying in your comments and unclear what the question means to ask. Might you perhaps consider enlisting the aid of a translation program?

Comment: [Google çeviri](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=google+translate) oldukça iyi çalışıyor. Belki bunu dene. Because clarity would help us help you.

Comment: Do you mean to ask why different cancers metastasize to specific locations? https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1535610805002345

Comment: No. Maybe because a healthy cell cannot get enough glucose from the blood, it expresses a protein and this activates a signaling pathway (like hormones) in the cancer cell. This cancer cell then migrates to the healthy cell. Yes my english is not good but it is not that hard to understand!!!

Comment: Well,  the absence of such a reason in a review about specific localization of metastases lowers its probability though.

Comment: @Furkan I want to know what the goal/objective is of what you're asking; I think that would help the rest of us figure out what it is you're trying to ask.

Comment: I love science and I'm curious. I have no other purpose

Comment: Although not by glucose as you mentioned. https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/30423299/ Ca seems to have the ability

Comment: @user237650 Finally, someone understood what I meant. thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you are wondering whether a cancerous cell might be 'recruited' to a healthy organ because that organ is releasing some sort of molecule that the cancerous cell recognizes in some sense and that results in the cancer cell moving toward the higher gradient, until eventually it is at the organ.

With respect to flowing towards a gradient in blood: A cancerous cell that has found its way into the bloodstream will be at the mercy of the *flow* of the blood and not much else. If you've ever seen a video of how aggressively red blood cells get moved through the blood, a cancer cell will similarly move in the direction of the flow, regardless of any molecular gradient that is or isn't present. This flow will carry the cancerous cell through the body and it seems implausible that any molecular gradient will have any impact on this.

With respect to chemotaxis in an area that has no pressure gradient (i.e., a cell 'crawling' over organ A to get to organ B because of some signalling molecules being released by organ B) there is simply no evidence that I'm aware of that this occurs.